# How to give GPKG layer as output in processing algorithm?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, qgis-3

I try to use `qgis:creategrid` processing tool. I want to give as output source gpkg layer which I have already create by defining it shape type, crs. However it does not work for me now. Here is my code:

```
parameters = {'TYPE': 2,
              'EXTENT': '%f,%f,%f,%f' % (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax),
              'HSPACING': dx,
              'VSPACING': dy,
              'HOVERLAY': 0.0,
              'VOVERLAY': 0.0,
              'CRS': str(epsg),
              'OUTPUT': self.gpkgFile + "|layername=Grid_1"}

processing.run('qgis:creategrid', parameters)
```

`self.gpkgFile` is defined the gpkg source such as: `D:\newProject\project1.gpkg`

So `'OUTPUT'` describes here: `D:\newProject\project1.gpkg|layername=Grid_1`

How can I use gpkg layer as `'OUTPUT'`in such kind of processing tools?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try specifying the output string as a full layer Uri, E.g.

```
"ogr:dbname='d:/package.gpkg' table=\"mylayer\" (geom) sql="
```

The easiest way to determine a valid string is to run the algorithm from the toolbox and then check the history panel - it will include all the parameter values including the output strings, so you could then copy and adapt those.

Comment: If you want to add a new layer into an existing gpkg database be aware to open it in update mode, otherwise the old gpkg data file will be overwritten. Ogr2ogr is using the -update switch for that by I do not know how to do that with pyqgis.